# VS __forceinline in cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Can I use `__forceinline` in .cpp file wtih VS 2013?

From this manual's examples it seems to be possible
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx . But I want to be sure.

Comment: Have you *tried* it? What happened then? Also note the beginning of the second line in the linked documentation page.

Comment: Why not fire up the compiler and give it a try?

Comment: I don't have VS on hand. I thought, maybe someone use it in .cpp

Comment: From the documentation you linked: `The __inline and __forceinline keywords are available in both C and C++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, and it's actually enforced really well (unlike gcc/clang etc, where `__attribute__((always_inline))` is unfortunatly still optional for the compiler, depending on multiple other compiler flag settings).

The keyword works in all versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I read the link you gave. The page does explicitly say it is for VS 2013. Try it out and step through the code with the debugger to be certain.